# How to echo image url variable into background url

Tags: php, loops, url

Anyone can help me how to insert my loop variable inside image url using this code below.

I have this code.

```
<?php echo '<li class=" parallax" style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/1200x500&amp;text=IMAGE+PLACEHOLDER);"></li>'?>
```

but my problem is how can i insert this code inside my background-image url

```
<?php _che($item['url']);?>
```

I try this code but it's not working

```
<?php echo '<li class=" parallax" style="background-image:url('._che($item['url']);.'"></li>'?>
```

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue in your concatenation. Try this

```
<?php echo '<li class=" parallax" style="background-image:url('._che($item['url']).');"></li>'?>
```

Comment: it shows blank 

this is my updated code.

<?php foreach ($slideshow_images as $key => $item):?>
        <?php echo '<li class=" parallax" style="background-image:url('.($item['url']).';"></li>'?>
         <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: Ha yes sorry, I let a typo. A closing ")" is missing. I update my post. If it's still empty, you can do `var_dump($item['url'])` to check if the value is set or not.

Comment: Still not showing when I do inspect element image url shows before li

it showing like this

              http://localhost/pbpro/files/house-interior-m-1.jpg
<li class="parallax" style="background-image: url("";); width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: none;"></li>

Comment: Your code is still `<?php foreach ($slideshow_images as $key => $item):?> <?php echo '<li class=" parallax" style="background-image:url('.($item['url']).');"></li>'?> <?php endforeach; ?> ` ? Or do you use the _che() function ?

Comment: It worked !

I change **_che** to **_simg** 

Thankyou !